# Database Returning no results

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've recently upgraded from perfectly working CodeIgniter v2.2.0 to CodeIgniter v3.0.1 for better session handling. In doing so all calls to the database regardless of which `$database['dbdriver']` is used return nothing. I've also tried inputting a `$config` array directly into the database loader like so: `$this->load->database($config);` but this didn't work either. I've tried using the PDO and MySQLi drivers and both return the same thing:

**MySQLi:**

```
string 'SELECT *
FROM `ns_users`' (length=24)
object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)[26]
  public 'conn_id' => 
    object(mysqli)[24]
      public 'affected_rows' => null
      public 'client_info' => null
      public 'client_version' => null
      public 'connect_errno' => null
      public 'connect_error' => null
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'error_list' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'host_info' => null
      public 'info' => null
      public 'insert_id' => null
      public 'server_info' => null
      public 'server_version' => null
      public 'stat' => null
      public 'sqlstate' => null
      public 'protocol_version' => null
      public 'thread_id' => null
      public 'warning_count' => null
  public 'result_id' => 
    object(mysqli_result)[25]
      public 'current_field' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'lengths' => null
      public 'num_rows' => null
      public 'type' => null
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'row_data' => null
```

**PDO:**

```
string 'SELECT *
FROM `ns_users`' (length=24)
object(CI_DB_pdo_result)[26]
  public 'conn_id' => 
    object(PDO)[23]
  public 'result_id' => 
    object(PDOStatement)[25]
      public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT *
FROM `ns_users`' (length=24)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'row_data' => null
```

The simple query I'm trying to run is, so that I can see that data is being pulled from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM `ns_users`
```

The table is definitely not empty, it contains more than 3 million login records, i've even tried to throw in a limit of 1 in case the amount of records/data was too much.

Am I missing anything that is supposed to be in my configuration or something? the following is my configuration (keep in mind I have CI set up to handle multiple applications on the same CI installation)

**config/database.php**

```
<?php
$db['users'] = array(
    'dsn'      => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=apps_control',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '***********',
    'password' => '***********',
    'database' => 'apps_control',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => TRUE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
define('USERS_DB_GROUP', 'users');
```

**controllers/test.php**

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('Users');
        var_dump($this->Users->get_all_users());
        exit;
    }
}
```

**models/users.php**

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Model {

    private $table_name;
    private $udb;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function init($config = null){
        if(!empty($config) && is_array($config))
            $this->udb = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
        else
            $this->udb = $this->load->database(USERS_DB_GROUP, TRUE);
        if(!$this->table_name)
            $this->table_name = $this->udb->dbprefix('ns_users');
    }
    public function get_all_users(){
        $this->init();
        $result = $this->udb->get($this->table_name);
        var_dump($this->udb->last_query());
        var_dump($result);exit;
        if($result && $result->num_rows > 0){
            return $result->result_array();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm just at a loss of what I'm missing here.

Comment: I believe they completely rewrote the session class in CI 3.x http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1657.html

Comment: I upgraded for sessions, but it broke the database connection. I just want to be able to run a select query

Comment: Are you receiving any connection or query errors?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus nope. it's connecting and running queries, but no data is being selected.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing this `$this->udb = $this->load->database` what the meaning? You could just autoload the database library? and then use codeigniter active records.

Comment: hard to debug such a long code and asking debugging help at SO is off-topic.

Comment: try this and check what you got `$result = $this->udb->get($this->table_name)->result();var_dump($result);`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 because I have 7 database groups that load at different points in the application depending on what the user does.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam going straight to the result worked! I've got a lot of model updating to do now, make an answer please so I can accept it

Comment: Out of interest, where did you get version 3.0.1 from? Latest version on their website is 3.0.0. If you're using dev code, this *could* be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `var_dump($result)` shows your `num_rows` 0

Try to compare your result using [num_rows()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=num_rows#CI_DB_result::num_rows) (as function)

```
if($result && $result->num_rows() > 0){
```

But I would write the function like this

```
public function get_all_users()
{
    $this->init();
    $result = $this->udb->get($this->table_name)->result_array();

    if($result)//check if our array empty or not.
    {
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```